# I want to create a sorted list of nom duplicated

Tags: python, list, linked-list, vb6, sortedlist

I need to create a sorted list with billions of elements and then create a second list without duplicate elements containing the first letter of each element of the first list and the position of this element in the first list.

```
#input
"Alfa", "Bravo","Big","Bang","Charlie" 

#output
"A",1, "B",2, "C",5
```

Comment: Homework assignment?

Comment: @matisetorm Hmm, I'd say people who get homework assignments don't usually have computers that can hold a list with billions of strings.

Comment: You can't reasonably create a list of strings of that size. If you have billions of elements you'll have to work with external storage. Put them in a file, use a file-based sort to get the file in sequence, then read through the resulting sorted file constructing your summary list.

Comment: Why is this post tagged as both vb6 AND python?  At least one of those tags should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear whether you need to keep results of the first sort for anything other than producing the second list, nor why there are VB6 and Python tags on this question.

If you think that you need a temporary array for the final result, then you are wrong!

Just iterate over a list of elements, preferably in the batched manner (you load some elements, the process then, then "unload"/free them from memory).
From each element take the only the first letter. If this letter is not yet in your output array, then add it with count `1`. If it's already in it, increment its counter.

So for 
`"Alfa","Charlie", "Big", "Bravo","Bang"`

You will get:
`A => 1, C => 1, B => 3"`

Then sort it by the keys.
`A => 1, B => 3, C => 1"`

Then, and it's important, add each previous counter the the next one:
`A => 1, B => 3+1, C => 1+3+1"`

And you get your output.

PS It really was school/course, assignment, right? The trick was to find those optimizations. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
inlist=["Alfa", "Bravo","Big","Bang","Charlie"]

outlist=[]

for i in inlist:

    alpha=i[0]

    if not alpha in outlist:
        outlist.append(alpha)
        outlist.append(inlist.index(i)+1)
print(outlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sorting Python 3.0 and above have built in sort() method for the lists.
So to get the first sorted list.

`input_list =["Alfa","Charlie", "Big", "Bravo","Bang"]
 input_list.sort()`

For your second question @przemo_li 's answer is the most efficient one